# Wrong recursive function to find number of possible routes

Tags: python, recursion, directed-graph

I'm using a nested dictionary to indicate a graph's vertices and edges, like:

```
[ 
A: [B,D,E],
B: [C],
C: [D,E],
D: [C,E],
E: [B]
]
```

This is my code so far:

```
def number_of_trips(self, start_point, end_point, maxstops):
    return self._find_path(start_point, end_point, 0, 0, maxstops)

def _find_path(self, point_a, end_point, current_stops, routes, maxstops):
    current_stops += 1

    if current_stops > maxstops:
        return routes

    if end_point in self.digraph[point_a]:
        return routes + 1
    else:
        for x in self.digraph[point_a]:
            return self._find_path(x, end_point, current_stops, routes, maxstops)

    return routes
```

And the method is called like this:

```
number_of_trips('C', 'C', 3)
```

Which outputs 1 instead of 2.

What is wrong with my recursive function?

Comment: I think you should somehow sum up all the routes from next recursions instead of `return` them. In your `else` branch, you will `return` at your first `x` instead of looping all `self.digraph[point_a]`.

Comment: You're not updating the value of `routes` ever!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with the following code:

```
def _find_path(self, point_a, end_point, current_stops, routes, maxstops):
        current_stops += 1

        if current_stops > maxstops:
            return routes

        if end_point in self.digraph[point_a]:
            return 1
        else:
            for x in self.digraph[point_a]:
                routes += self._find_path(x, end_point, current_stops, routes, maxstops)

        return routes
```

Answer (score 1):

Increment the `routes` value when recursive call is made:

```
return self._find_path(x, end_point, current_stops, routes + 1, maxstops)
```

Comment: The routes variable is incremented just in case of a complete route between point A and B